# Taking an average of every 2 data points in an array, creating a new array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to take the average of every 2 values in an array and store the new data in a new array.

This is as far as I can get:

```
y1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

avgy = [0]*(len(y1)//2)

for i in range (0, len(y1)-1):
    if (2*(1+i)<=len(y1)):
        avgy[i] = ( y1[i+2[i]] + y1[2+2*i] )/2

print(avgy)
```

This is the error message I get:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-624d78987390> in <module>()
      9 for i in range (0, len(y1)-1):
     10     if (2*(1+i)<=len(y1)):
---> 11         avgy[i] = ( y1[i+2[i]] + y1[2+2*i] )/2
     12 
     13 print(avgy)

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I would appreciate any help that can be given.
Oliver

Comment: What exactly is `i+2[i]` supposed to do?  That is what is causing your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a simple typo. `y1[i+2[i]] + y1[2+2*i]` should be

```
y1[2*i] + y1[2*i+1]
```

Python lists start at index 0.

You may need to adjust your `if`.

Answer (score 1):

```
y1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)]

avgy = ((y1 + np.roll(y1,1))/2.0)[1::2]
```

EDIT: this method works around 20x faster than using for loop and around 90x faster than using zip and list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

A neat (if a bit tricky) way to do this is to use slices and `zip` in a creative way - see console transcript below.

```py
# Input data.
>>> y1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# Look at the even and odd values.
>>> y1[::2], y1[1::2]
([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10])

# Use zip to transpose these two lists of five into five lists of two.
>>> zip(*(y1[::2], y1[1::2]))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]

# Use a list comprehension over the pairs to average them.
>>> [(a + b) / 2. for (a, b) in zip(*(y1[::2], y1[1::2]))]
[1.5, 3.5, 5.5, 7.5, 9.5]
```

This will crash if the list's length isn't divisible by two.

Answer (score 0):

```
y1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

avgy = []
for i in range(0,len(y1),2):
    avgy.append((y1[i]+y1[i+1])/2)

print(avgy)
```

This will give you a list with averages